# Is it possible to generate scripts from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to generate scripts from SQL Server 2008 that can then be used in SQL Server Express editions or is it not possible. I read it is not possible, but is there another way.

Comment: Write or use SSMS to do them for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - what are you trying to do??

SQL Server and the Express editions are *binary compatible* - you could even just create a backup on your "full" SQL Server and restore it on your Express version....

Comment: Instead of doing a backup, I went through Database > task > generate scripts > selected tables. In addition, don't have access to SQL server or authority to specify backup location.

Answer (score 1):

unless you are using features that are in Enterprise Edition and up (like data compression, partitioning, etc etc) the scripts should be fine to run on Express edition